# Dealing with pixels in real-time using OpenCV

Tags: python

I just started to study OpenCV with Python and was trying to build my first game bot. My thought is: capture the game window frame by frame and analyze the pixels in some specific locations, if the color of those pixels has changed, then press a key to do some automatic operations.

This game needs quick reactions so the FPS is quite important, I have tried the mss and PIL, but the fps in both methods are not enough (30+ with mss and 10+ with PIL's ImageGrab), so I'm wondering if there is any better way to deal with pixels in real-time. Thanks!

Comment: As jacub said going with GPU is a good option, but another good factor is the language that you're using, I should suggest you use C or C++ as they are somewhat faster languages, but on the other hand, it'll take you more effort to  do it with those as it's not as easy as writing `from PIL import *` as it is in python.

Answer (score 2):

I've been through same problem, as I wanted to do same thing.
The main problem is that you are using CPU to do all operations, and you are not using much of its power.

You may either optimize your program or use more power. Try this:

- Reading about using GPU with python (e.g. CUDA)
- Trying to do OpenCV operations on less data - e.g. converting RGB to gray scale, decreasing ROI

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ks4MPfMq8aQ&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDeETZEOy4VdocT7TOjfSA8a

OpenCV has GPU module, but only for C++.

It is not much information, but I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks dude, I will try to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Want to continue Jakubs great answer:

Using C++ or something might be a good idea in some cases.

I created a csgo aimbot with opencv, pil, pyautogui and numpy and few other modules, watching sentdex's videos on this subject might give u some idea(link above).

There might be a custom module for GPU cv2

*tips for py:*
1) lower imagegrab resolution.
2) in imagegrab.grab bbox you can give coordinates on which the grabs will happen instead of full screen.
3) grayscale is 0-255 so it will speed up the process, if u know which colors are in this reaction thingy just pass them to grayscale so u know in which colors to respond to.